# how to make sencha touch ui floating on top of ios native video?

Tags: sencha-touch-2.1

we are using an app using sencha touch and cordova for iphone.

the problem is we r using video.which plays on sencha components and every thing is

behind the video?

how to overcome it using sencha ??

Comment: it would really help other to understand your problem if you can share what have you done so far and what exactly the issue

Comment: @user2720864 thanks for ur reply.my problem is ios video is played on sencha components